# Getting 401 unauthorized when attempting to update custom measure through API

Tags: sonarqube

So I have created a custom metric, named "test_count" and added to a project as a custom measure. I can query the measure with REST

```
GET /api/custom_measures/search
```

Given the projectKey as parameters and f=metric, I get

```
{
  "customMeasures": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "metric": {
        "id": "145",
        "key": "test_count",
        "type": "INT",
        "name": "Test Count",
        "domain": "Coverage"
      }
    }
  ],
  "total": 1,
  "p": 1,
  "ps": 100
}
```

So far so good. Note that I authorized myself with `/api/authentication` prior to this.

Now I want to update this custom measure. I POSTed the to the following

```
POST /api/custom_measures/update
```

given the id and value as parameters. But I get 401. I've tried with id `1` as well as `145`, but both returns with 401. Needless to say, the measurement didn't go through.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your credentials *with* the POST.

Comment: Tried sonar-gw/api/custom_measures/update?id=1&value=2&login=admin&password=admin (yeah I didn't change the admin credentials, don't judge me), but still no go. Note that POST to sonar-gw/api/authentication/login?login=admin&password=admin returns with 200 OK